# Is there a clean way to limit Realm Object Server sync to wifi connections only?

Tags: ios, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am in the middle stages of an app development that uses Realm on the iOS handset and will synchronise data to ROS.  The amount of data that it could generate could become quite large, so we would like to offer the user the choice of only synchronising when they have a wifi connection to protect their mobile data quotas.

I could achieve this by being careful about when the app logs on and off the server, but that is messy and will likely lead to errors.

Is there a clean way to set up the synchronisation engine to only perform syncs when the server url is accessible via a Wifi connection?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to limit sync on WiFi connection only, unfortunately. We have put it on our task list. https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/143 It will be implemented in the near future.